# Google Web Toolkit compiling error, could not find GTWCompiler

Tags: gwt

When I want to compile my GTW project I got this output in my console:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\Donatas\\Desktop\\b2b\\servlet" "-Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\Donatas\\Desktop\\b2b\\servlet" -DforceRedeploy=false -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
wsimport-init:
wsimport-client-ic:
files are up to date
wsimport-client-generate:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
GWT4NB https://github.com/gwt4nb/gwt4nb
GWT installation directory: C:\Users\Donatas\Desktop\b2b\lib\gwt-2.7.0
init:
do-gwt-compile-15:
GWT Compiling client-side code.
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler
C:\Users\Donatas\Desktop\b2b\servlet\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Donatas\Desktop\b2b\servlet\nbproject\build-gwt.xml:356: Java returned: 1
```

My build-gtw.xml 326 line is:

```
    <target name="-pre-dist" depends="-gwt-define-compile-unneeded">
        <antcall target="-gwt-print-dir"/>
326:    <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-15" />
        <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-16" />
        <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-17" />
        <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-20" />
        <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-23" />
        <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-25" />
    </target>
```

My build-gtw.xml 356 line is:

```
       <target name="do-gwt-compile-15" if="gwt.version.15" 
                unless="gwt.compile.unneeded" depends="-init-gwt-dir">
            <!-- You can override this property in the 'gwt.properties' file -->
            <property name="gwt.compiler.output.style" value="OBFUSCATED"/>
            <property name="gwt.compiler.logLevel" value="WARN"/>
            <echo>GWT Compiling client-side code.</echo>
            <java failonerror="true"
                  classname="com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler" fork="true"
line 356:         jvmargs="${gwt.compiler.jvmargs}">
                <classpath>
                    <!--
                    GWT libraries are mentioned here explicitly so they are always
                    at the front of the class path.
                    -->
                    <pathelement path="${gwt.dir}/gwt-user.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${gwt.dir}">
                        <include name="gwt-dev-*.jar"/>
                    </fileset>
                    <pathelement path="${gwt.dir}/gwt-servlet.jar"/>
                    <pathelement path="${javac.classpath}"/>
                    <pathelement path="${src.dir}"/>
                    <pathelement path="${build.classes.dir}"/>
                </classpath>
                <arg value="-out"/>
                <arg path="${build.web.dir}/"/>
                <arg value="-style"/>
                <arg value="${gwt.compiler.output.style}"/>
                <arg value="-logLevel"/>
                <arg value="${gwt.compiler.logLevel}"/>
                <arg line="${gwt.compiler.args}"/>
                <arg line="${gwt.module}"/>
            </java>

            <property name="gwt.output.dir" value="${gwt.module}"/>

            <move todir="${build.web.dir}/${gwt.output.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${build.web.dir}/${gwt.module}"/>
            </move>
            <touch file="${build.dir}/gwtc.run"/>
        </target>
```

I know that GWTCompiler is deprecated, but how to change it if I change in Compiler I got error that my console arguments like [-out] is not recognized. So how to compile it. I'm using GTW 2.7 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in GWT4NB. It should invoke `do-gwt-compile-25` for GWT 2.7, not `do-gwt-compile-15`.

Try manually updating `build-gwt.xml` to add a 2.7 case to `gwt.version.25`: https://github.com/ksfreitas/gwt4nb/blob/1001c4fa8e9f6c0fed3c79ba19320b315737357f/trunk/src/org/netbeans/modules/gwt4nb/resources/build-gwt.xml#L139-L147

But it might not work, due to another bug (issue still open, don't know if it's been fixed or not, I don't use Netbeans): https://github.com/ksfreitas/gwt4nb/issues/32 (a quick grep in the code seems to indicate you could define gwt.version=2.6 or gwt.version=2.7 in `nbproject/gwt.properties` of your project, not sure if it'll work or be overwritten by the Netbeans plugin)

Comment: Add <equals arg1="${gwt.version}" arg2="2.7"/> to <or> in <condition property="gwt.version.25" value="true"> in build-gwt.xml and define gwt.version in gwt.properties from \ to 2.7   solved the issue ...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler hasn't been called `GWTCompiler` since GWT 1.7 or so. Use `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler` as the classname instead.

Comment: Also use `-war` in place of `-out`, and `gwt-dev.jar` instead of `gwt-dev-*.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

`<!--
    Check for GWT 2.5
    -->
    <condition property="gwt.version.25" value="true">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${gwt.version}" arg2="2.5"/>
            <equals arg1="${gwt.version}" arg2="2.6"/>
            <equals arg1="${gwt.version}" arg2="2.7"/> --> add this line
        </or>
    </condition>`

I added version 2.7 on **build-gwt.xml** and it works for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Open build-gwt.xml

Then,

Try removing:

```
  <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-15" />
```

Run, This should work